# Launch my CustomMediaplayer on clicking mp3 or radio urls in browser

Tags: android, audio, android-emulator, android-manifest

I have written a media player application for android 2.2. Now i need to launch(show my app in launcher menu)  my app when user clicks any Mp3 or Radio URLS in the browser.  Please suggest me ways to do this.

Thanks in advance.